# How to include static htmls in angular 2 component

Tags: angular

Different pages of my application show same static text. Is there a way by which I can externalize this text in HTML files and then include these files in different angular components.

Comment: Why not simply consider your text as a component?

Comment: Why not just store it in *.ts files and import it where you need it?

Comment: Static text mainly contains different regulations. There are around 30 different regulations in the application. I want to avoid creating so many components and adding them in the app.module. Is there a way to import *.html files?

Comment: I don't think so you can import multiple html file in one component, but u can use like this for single html file :
 templateUrl: './quest-summary.component.html',

Answer (score 1):

One way (really not the best, because of potential security flaws) would be to load your html files using `Http` and then include them in your `StaticHTMLComponent` (the html file has to be served by the webserver).

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-static-html',
    templateUri:'static-html.component.html'
})
export class StaticHTMLComponent {

    @Input() templatesUri: string[];

    constructor(private http: HttpService) {
    }

    loadTemplates(): Observable<string[]> {
        let templates: Observable<string>[] = [];
        this.templatesUri.forEach(uri => {
            templates.push(this.http.get(uri).map(res => res.text()));
        });
        return Observable.combineLatest(templates);
    }
}
```

With this template:

```
<div *ngFor="let template of loadTemplates() | async" [innerHTML]="template"></div>
```

### WARNING

As I said at the beginning of my answer, this may add security flaws to your code, and it has a lot of defaults to me.

First of all, **this will not allow you to load `css`** with your static HTML, as it's only meant to load html.

Then, **it opens a potential flaw** because if one of your static HTML files is corrupted, then you will still load it, with no problems.

Angular is not meant to serve static HTML files, this is a workaround but the best solution would be to serve those static HTML files using your own web server, isolating them from the angular application.